# Nodejs: Performance issues parsing CSV and Zip

Tags: node.js, performance, csv, stream, zip

The files are submitted to my server and I'm trying to determine if the CSV is valid and if all the images referenced from the CSV are present in the zip. I have to populate a Mongo database with all that information but I want to do it in the background, and send a response to the client as fast as possible.

So I have two readable streams and I have three different approaches:

- Unzipping the file takes 24sec, so unzip + parsing the csv + fs.exists is not an option.
- Parsing the whole csv, save filenames in array and then reading the zip using node-unzip and pipe takes 5 seconds.
- Reading the csv and in parallel read the zip and use a shared array to determine simultaneusly if the files are present, which is the fastest option, takes 4 seconds.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do it faster?

**EDIT**: The code used for validation is:

```
// lib/validator.js

function validateParallel(csv, zip) {
  const shared = {};
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const l = CSV_VALIDATORS.length - 1;
    csv
      .pipe(split())
      .pipe(through2(validateLine.bind({ zip, reject, n: 0, l, shared })))
      .on('finish', () => {
        zip
         .pipe(unzip.Parse())
         .on('entry', (entry) => {
           delete shared[entry.path];
         })
         .on('close', () => {
           resolve(Object.keys(shared).length === 0);
         });
      });
  });
}

// perfomance/validate.spec.js

const zip = fs.createReadStream('./performance/imports/import.zip');
const csv = fs.createReadStream('./performance/imports/stress-test.csv');

const hrstart = process.hrtime();
validator
  .validateParallel(csv, zip)
  .then(function(isValid) {
    console.log(`valid=${isValid}`);
    const hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
    console.info("Execution time (hr): %ds %dms", hrend[0], hrend[1]/1000000);
});
```

ValidateLine takes the image name and pushes it into the shared object. The output is:

```
valid=true
Execution time (hr): 4s 926.031869ms
```

I have simplified the code and removed error management to make it more readable.

Comment: There should be an ability to get the contents of a zip file without unzipping the whole file and I would assume that should be faster.

Comment: Even when the file is in a stream? I've not found anything like that.

Comment: We would need to see your code.  It is possible to get the zip file entries from a stream without saving the whole zip file to disk.

Comment: I'll update with the code at night. Options 2 and 3 are without saving the file to disk, it weights about 40MB.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added the main code I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to also validate the images themselves, or just make sure their paths exist in the CSV file? If the latter, you can run a shell process that executes `unzip -l` on the zip file, which will print only the file names, should be quick.

Comment: Just if exists. But i would need to write the whole file to disk.

Comment: Still a lot faster than all your three solutions, which do (though indirectly) save the file anyway.
I'm not sure if you can rely on the zip format, but you might be able to sniff the file names from the beginning of the stream, so you don't have to continue reading it.

Comment: The solutions 2 and 3 parses the zip file in memory not disk. Pipe the file directly to disk without parsing anything takes 24sec, although `unzip -l` is faster i cannot wait 24 seconds for responding.

Comment: 1. Can you get the list of file names from the header of the zip? This depends on the zip format. 2. Are you in control of your source streams? Maybe you can change them so that you get the list of file names in a separate request before you stream the zip file.

Comment: I have read that Zip stores the central directory with all the entries at the end of the file so, that would be no possible. I could do that but it would be pointless because this validation is implemented to avoid human errors. I could ask for the users to upload a file with the list of compressed files but I think It would be useless.

Comment: Looks like you need to wait for the whole zip file to get in then. If this is your bottleneck then I don't see any way around waiting the 4 seconds.